# Permission not changing

Tags: permissions

[image][image]Why I can't change permission of any files which are located on other partitions like sda2,sda3,sda4 and so on.. When I change it from properties it's immediately change again to it's previous setting.. When I tried with nautilus... it shows

Comment: did you try chmod

Comment: Yes !! But same...

Comment: What is the filesystem type on the devices (not all filesystems support Unix-style permissions)? How are they mounted?

Comment: It's NTFS and automatically mounted..

Comment: check that http://askubuntu.com/a/11843/179030

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you don't have sufficient  privileges to change the permissions in the first place.

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then entering `gksudo nautilus`. Once you've entered your password, the file browser (`nautilus`) should launch, and you should be able to change those permissions.

You can also do this from the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running the `chown` command.

Eg: `sudo chown [USER]:[USER] /media/USER/FOLDER/FILE`

Comment: I tried chown but nothing changed

Comment: @PriyankaNath What command exactly did you use?

Comment: sudo chown pnath:pnath /filename

Comment: Any help!!!!!!!!

Comment: @PriyankaNath I believe the answer linked to by Anıl Karaağaç [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition) should solve your problem. Since the partition is an NTFS partition, the normal Unix/Linux file permissions don't apply, since it's a Windows filesystem.